# Laravel Form Request not being passed to argument

Tags: php, validation, laravel, authentication, request

I'm busy migrating an app from Laravel 4.2 to 5.1, and am experiencing an issue with Form Requests. It's probably something simple that I'm missing - not really sure.

The method below is meant to attempt a sign in if `SignInRequest` successfully authorises the request. However, if the validation passes, `SignInRequest` is not passed to `attemptSignIn`, which throws the process off with this error:

> Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::attemptSignIn() must be an instance of App\Http\Requests\SignInRequest, none given

This is the method (controller is `AuthController`) in question, which tries to sign in using a username or an email address:

```php
public function attemptSignIn($type = 'regular', SignInRequest $request)
{
    switch ($type) {
        case 'regular':
            $identifierFieldName = 'account_identifier';
            $field = filter_var($request->input($identifierFieldName), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
            $request->merge([$field => $request->input($identifierFieldName)]);
            $specifics = $request->only($field, 'passphrase');
            $specifics['activated'] = (int) true;
            if ($this->auth->attempt($specifics)) {
                return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath);
            } else {
                return redirect($this->signInPath)
                    ->with('authError', "The credentials you've provided are incorrect.")
                    ->with('authErrorType', 'warning')
                    ->withInput($request->only($identifierFieldName))
                    ->withErrors();
            }
            break;

        case 'oota':

            break;

        default:
            return redirect($this->signInPath);
            break;
    }
}
```

The form request is straight-forward, specifying `rules`, `messages` and `authorize` (`return true`).

If the validation fails, however, `SignInRequest` is passed to the method, and the errors are shown accordingly.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: did you inject `SignInRequest` in your controller?

Comment: `attemptSignIn` is a controller method. Are you saying I need to also inject it into the constructor?

Comment: The second arg `SignInRequest ` passed to the method has to be injected or int at constructor

Comment: So, I should assign `$this->request` to the form request in the constructor? if so, I would be unable to `withErrors()` in `attemptSignIn`, unless errors are passed to the view automatically...

Comment: you don't need to pass the errors, they are passed by default. [https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/3](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/3) check the video, it s very helpful.

Comment: Okay thanks, guessed that might be the case. Unfortunately limited in bandwidth this week, but I understand how to fix this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use \path\to\your\ClassRequest as MyRequest
```

or

```
protected $myrequest;

public function __construct(\path\to\your\ClassRequest $request){
   $this -> myrequest = $request; // use directly in your method or any method
}
```

Hope this help.

```
public function post_form(MyRequest $request) {
  your code here

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. If I use the first method, I get the exception. If I inject it into the constructor and assign to `$this->request`, I get a redirect loop between `/signin` and `/dashboard`.

Comment: Apologies, that was an earlier redirect loop. `/signin` keeps redirecting to itself, but there is no instruction for it to do so. I may just switch back to manual validation on this one.

Comment: Ah, you were right - it appears that argument order was the problem. It appears to be working now, only it isn't authenticating with valid credentials. Will figure that out separately. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.